# Using Maven Cargo artifactInstaller for GlassFish 3.x

Tags: maven, glassfish, maven-cargo

Is there a way to use Cargo's `artifactInstaller` element to install a GlassFish container during maven-cargo-plugin's `run` goal?

More specifically, is there a ZIP artifact available in a Maven repository, which contains the required GlassFish files as is the case for Jetty, for which we have the org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-distribution artifact?

Answer (score 1):

Yes sir. In fact... no, there is none available (afaik).

But you can easily install one locally (or deploy it to your own repository using the following command :

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=glassfish3.1.1.zip -DgroupId=org.glassfish -DartifactId=glassfish-installer -Dversion=3.1.1 -Dpackaging=zip
```

Then you'll need to declare your artifact installer like this :

```
<artifactInstaller>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>glassfish-installer</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1</version>
</artifactInstaller>
```

It's a bit late compare to your post... but hope this helps ;)

Cheers,
Pouce.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another solution:

If you need the web distribution, you can use the following:

```
<groupId>org.glassfish.distributions</groupId>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
```

Or, if you need another distribution, just browse [the list of glassfish distributions](http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/distributions/) to find the one suitable for your needs.